# Jsf not put the value in var

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've tried all the ways, but do not understand how it does not work.
I have this dataTable, but in no way do I insert the value in inputText goes to the variable in backBean.

What I want is that when the User enter the value, this value for the va backBean along with the object to write to the base. The problem is that in any way the value is set in the variable. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

DataTable:

```
 <p:dataTable id="dataTable"
                             var="XmlItens"
                             paginator="true"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="100"
                             rows="100"
                             value="#{xmlItensBean.listaDataModel}"  
                             emptyMessage="Você ainda não ativou uma empresa ou não existe postagem para esta Empresa">

                    <p:column headerText="Descrição">
                        #{XmlItens.descricaoProd}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Cod. Fornecedor">
                        #{XmlItens.codProdFor}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="EAN">
                        #{XmlItens.eanProd}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="CNPJ Fornecedor">
                        #{XmlItens.cnpjFor}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Numero NFE">
                        #{XmlItens.numnfe}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Cod. Cliente">
                        <p:inputText value="#{XmlItens.codProdCli}" >
                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{xmlItensBean.updateCodProd(XmlItens)}"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

My problem is in cod. cliente.
The value `codProdCli` dont go to backbean.

Bean:

```
    public void updateCodProd(XmlItens item) {
    dao.updateCodigoCliente(item);
}
```

Comment: Is that your xhtml code under <h:form>

Comment: Yes but I do not know what to do.

Comment: Tell us the scope of your bean?

Comment: i use viewScoped in this bean.

Comment: Try instead of passing an object through the listener, pass the field `codProdCli`: `listener="#{xmlItensBean.updateCodProd(XmlItens.codProdCli)}"/>`  with changing the method in the backing-bean as  `public void updateCodProd(Long item) {
Cliente c = dao.searchCodigoCliente(item);
dao.updateCodigoCliente(c);
}`

Comment: The entered value is not passed to the bean. Why is that?

Comment: The change event doesn't activate until the inputText value has been changed and it loses focus. Have you tried changing the text and then clicking somewhere else on the page to remove focus from the inputText?

Comment: You'll need to post full xhtml and backbean code.